# Why is 'not(True) * True' valid syntax, unlike 'True * not(True)'?

Tags: python, syntax, operator-precedence

Is this a consequence of the hierarchical order of operators in Python?

```
not(True) * True
# False
True * not(True)
# SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Your parentheses are in the wrong places. The first line should be `(not True) * True` and the second should be `True * (not True)`. In your second line, you're multiplying `True` and `not`, which is a syntax error. `not` is not a function, so you don't use parens after it.

Comment: Why is is a *syntax error* as opposed to a runtime type mismatch, though?

Comment: Note: The parentheses are a red herring. `True * not True` produces the same syntax error.

Comment: @John What types are there to mismatch? The only objects involved here are booleans.

Comment: @wjandrea `not` is not a boolean, it is an operator.

Comment: @mpez0 Right... and an operator is not an object, so it doesn't have a type per se

Comment: Why would anyone multiply booleans?

Comment: @JohnKugelman Nice find. Didn't expect this to be duplicated.

Comment: "Fascinating" as Spock would say, I wonder does this apply when using SymPy?

Answer (score 34):

> Is this a consequence of the hierarchical order of operators in Python?

Yes (although the usual term is [*operator precedence*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)). Summing up and simplifying:

1. `not` isn't a function; it's an *operator*. Therefore, we don't need to write parentheses for `not (True)`, and in fact they don't do anything here. All that happens is that the parentheses are treated as ordinary *grouping* parentheses - `(True)` is evaluated before anything else, becoming `True`. So, let's consider the examples without the parentheses.
2. `not True * True` means `not (True * True)`. It does **not** mean `(not True) * True`, due to operator precedence. This is by design:

   ```
   >>> not 1 * 0
   True
   >>> not (1 * 0)
   True
   >>> (not 1) * 0
   0
   ```

   It would, the developers figured, be unexpected to write something like `not 1 * 0` and get an integer result, and unexpected to write `not` in front of a mathematical operation and have the `not` only apply to the first thing in that expression.
3. Because of that same operator precedence, `True * not True` is a syntax error. Python parses the `not` by itself as the right-hand side of the `*`, because it hasn't yet worked out to put `not True` together. `True * not` is obviously nonsense. Or, another way of looking at it: "`not` followed by an expression" isn't in the list of "things that can be an operand for `*`".

   This is perhaps surprising because the *other* commonly used unary operator, `-` (i.e., unary negation), doesn't have this issue. But that's because the precedence is the other way around: unary negation is processed before multiplication, not after.

   The same is true for `and` and `or` combinations:

   ```
   >>> 3 * 5 and 1 # 3 * 5 is evaluated first
   1
   >>> 3 * (5 and 1)
   3
   >>> 3 or 1 * 5 # 1 * 5 is evaluated first, even though it comes later
   3
   >>> (3 or 1) * 5
   15
   ```

Comment: Unary operators that don't bind tightly are sort of nuts.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Indeed. All other languages I know don't give you syntax errors in this case -- they just compute another (unexpected) value.

Comment: It looks like this answer might be making the mistake of thinking that precedence controls evaluation order. Precedence doesn't force evaluation order. It just controls what's an argument to what. For example, in `a + b + c * d`, `a + b` is evaluated before `c * d`, as you can see by [overloading the operators](https://ideone.com/sKGkp9).

Comment: Grouping parentheses don't force their contents to be evaluated first, and the parse failure for `True * not True` isn't "because it hasn't had a chance to apply `not True` yet". (The ""`not` followed by an expression" isn't in the list of "things that can be an operand for `*`"" part is correct.)

Comment: @user2357112 Well, precedence controls evaluation order *when there's a dependency* - analogous to how arguments to a function have to be evaluated before it's called. It's hard to be precise and also clear for beginners. But you do have a good point. I'll review it later. The specific "hasn't had a chance" wording, I'll try to think of something.

Comment: I didn't have a lot of good ideas, but I think this fixes it.

Answer (score 12):

This is a matter of precedence, and how precedence is implemented.

`*` has a higher precedence than `not`, and the way that works in the Python grammar is that there's a hierarchy of expression types, structured so that higher-precedence operators can be the "root" operator of an argument to a lower-precedence operator, but not the other way around.

For example, the [grammar rule](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.6/Grammar/python.gram#L655) for multiplicative expressions is

```
term[expr_ty]:
    | a=term '*' b=factor { _PyAST_BinOp(a, Mult, b, EXTRA) }
    | a=term '/' b=factor { _PyAST_BinOp(a, Div, b, EXTRA) }
    | a=term '//' b=factor { _PyAST_BinOp(a, FloorDiv, b, EXTRA) }
    | a=term '%' b=factor { _PyAST_BinOp(a, Mod, b, EXTRA) }
    | a=term '@' b=factor { CHECK_VERSION(expr_ty, 5, "The '@' operator is", _PyAST_BinOp(a, MatMult, b, EXTRA)) }
    | factor
```

`term` is the grammar rule for multiplicative expressions. The first 5 options in this rule consist of a multiplicative-precedence operator in the middle, another `term` on the left of the operator, and a `factor` on the right, where `factor` is the rule for the next higher-precedence operator class. The 6th option is just a `factor`.

Structuring the grammar like this makes sure the parsed syntax tree always matches the structure given by operator precedence, but it also means that lower-precedence operators cannot be the "root" operator of an argument to a higher-precedence operator, even when the expression would seem unambiguous. There's just no grammar rule that would allow a `not` expression as an argument to a `*` expression.

(The grammar rules for most expressions follow the above structure, but there are exceptions. For example, the grammar rules for parentheses don't follow the "no lower-precedence operators within higher-precedence expressions" structure, which is why you can write things like `3 * (4 + 5)`. Exponentiation is another exception - `**` binds tighter than a unary `+`/`-`/`~` on the left, but not on the right, so the rules for `**` and unary `+`/`-`/`~` don't follow a clear precedence hierarchy.)

Comment: The other unary operators (`+x`, `-x`, `~x`) have lower precedence than exponentiation `**` -- so a similar effect *should* be seen here: `42 ** ~ 2` But this expression *does* work. So I smell another special case :-)

Comment: @A.H.: Yeah, I mentioned that in the last paragraph. Those unary operators aren't strictly lower-precedence than `**`. There's even a footnote under the [precedence table](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) pointing out how `**` sort of has different precedence on each side. In the [grammar](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.6/Grammar/python.gram#L662-L669), you can see that this is implemented by having `power` take a `factor` instead of a `power` on the RHS. (`factor` is the rule for unary `+`/`-`/`~`.)